# Best way to extract domain name in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an URL e.g `http://test.example.com` I need to extract `test` (sub domain of this url.) from this url. This url is dynamic it may change so couldn't match with `test` and extract it. I have written block of code it is working for me. Can anyone suggest me better way to achieve this.

```
var siteUrl = 'http://test.example.com';
var parts = siteUrl.split('.');
var subdomainstr = parts.shift(); // Output 'http://test'
var upperleveldomain = parts.join('.'); // Output 'example.com'


var extractSubDomain = subdomainstr.split('//');
var subdomain = extractSubDomain.slice(1).join('.');

console.log(subdomain); //Output test
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGDxH/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not this?

```
var subdomain = siteUrl.split('//')[1].split('.')[0];
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YGDxH/1/)

Comment: @Roopendra glat it helped

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer regex, this works

```
var subdomain = siteUrl.match(/http:\/\/([^\.]*)/i)[1];
```